# Return a function parameter based on function result

Tags: t-sql

In my simplified example scenario, my objective is to return the sensor temperature (called "TemperatureOfRecord") that is closest to 70 degrees, given a particular timestamp and building. For example, building #1's TemperatureOfRecord for the 8:00 a.m. timestamp is 65 degrees because 65 degrees is closer to 70 degrees than 80 degrees is. The "Delta" column is a computed column that returns the absolute value of the sensor temperature minus 70 degrees. I use the differential to test each sensor temperature against the target temperature of 70 degrees.

The nested correlated subquery below returns the correct results, but I am having a lot of trouble scaling this approach out for my actual scenario. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is a simpler approach that I could use.

```
SELECT
    tt.TmStamp
    , tt.Building
    , tt.Sensor
    , tt.Temperature
    , tt.Delta
    , (SELECT tt2.Temperature
        FROM dbo.TempTest tt2
        WHERE tt2.Building = tt.Building
            AND tt2.TmStamp = tt.TmStamp
            AND tt2.Delta = 
            (SELECT MIN(tt3.Delta)
            FROM dbo.TempTest tt3
            WHERE tt3.Building = tt.Building
                AND tt3.TmStamp = tt.TmStamp)
    ) AS TemperatureOfRecord
FROM dbo.TempTest tt
```

The results of the above query are below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attempt to use a CTE instead. [Here's a SQLFiddle too.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0912/2) I've compared the execution plans of the two queries as well - and even though the CTE cost more, it only had about a third the amount of scans/reads than the subquery method.

```
WITH rec AS (
    SELECT TmStamp, Building, Temperature, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TmStamp, Building ORDER BY Delta) AS RowOrder
    FROM dbo.TempTest
)
SELECT
    tt.TmStamp
    , tt.Building
    , tt.Sensor
    , tt.Temperature
    , tt.Delta
    , rec.Temperature AS TemperatureOfRecord
FROM dbo.TempTest tt
JOIN rec
    ON tt.TmStamp = rec.TmStamp AND tt.Building = rec.Building
WHERE rec.RowOrder = 1
```